# How to return distinct records in case insensitive Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, rdbms

If I have 2 records with same information with difference in NAME of upper case and lower case and I want to show distinct record, how can I do it ? I tried to use distinct in query below but it showed both records :( Sorry but I am a green horn in SQL coding :(

```
SELECT distinct
R.NAME,
R.EXPIRY_DATE,
R.CATEGORY
FROM REALTIME_EXEMPT R
WHERE
R.SUBMITTED_BY='ADMIN'
```

Thanks in advance,

Reeya

Comment: Please post your table structure and sample output

Comment: make them lowercase or uppercase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct(upper(R.NAME)),
R.EXPIRY_DATE,
R.CATEGORY
FROM REALTIME_EXEMPT R
WHERE
R.SUBMITTED_BY='ADMIN'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the issue is that user can add a lower case name or upper case name. Also the names added may or may not be redundant. In such case, I cannot use UPPER or LOWER.

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi This answer will solve the problem you described. If you are still having a problem perhaps you should re-word your question and/or provide example output and desired output.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `UPPER` or `LOWER` keywords

```
SELECT distinct
UPPER(R.NAME),
R.EXPIRY_DATE,
R.CATEGORY
FROM REALTIME_EXEMPT R
WHERE
R.SUBMITTED_BY='ADMIN'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the issue is that user can add a lower case name or upper case name. Also the names added may or may not be redundant. In such case, I cannot use UPPER or LOWER.